# SQL File in liquibase never executed

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, liquibase

I'm using liquibase with maven and I have a configuration for unit test

```
<configuration>
    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
    <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;shutdown=true</url>                 
    <referenceUrl>persistence:webapp</referenceUrl>                 
    <username>sa</username>
    <password></password>
</configuration>
```

In my changelog I use an sqlFile tag to execute insert statments.

```
<changeSet id="18" author="naslami">
    <sqlFile path="src/main/resources/db/changelog/inserts.sql" />
</changeSet>
```

But when I look in the log, the *insert.sql* file is never executed.
Do you have and idea why liquibase does not execute the *insert.sql* file?

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>                                                                  
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</url>                 
                        <referenceUrl>persistence:webapp</referenceUrl>                 
                        <username>user</username>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </configuration> 
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>                                                                  
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                        <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;shutdown=true</url>                 
                        <referenceUrl>persistence:webapp</referenceUrl>                 
                        <username>sa</username>
                        <password></password>
                    </configuration> 
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Try to remove the `src/main/resources` part so that the path becomes `<changeLogFile>/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>` and `<sqlFile path="/db/changelog/inserts.sql" />`

Comment: nothing chenged. There is always no trace for the _inserts.sql_ file in the log

Comment: I tried also to add the sql script directly in the `sql tag` but always nothing new. No trace of the inserts

Comment: In fact I just noticed that the changelog is not executed at all

Comment: Try to move the change log inside `src/test/resources`.

Comment: Add ${basedir} : ${basedir}/src/main/resources

Comment: Not forget   <dependency><groupId>mysql</groupId>           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

Comment: I would go with flyway. It's must cleaner and much more fluent that Liquibase. Liquibase is all over the place. You have to deal with XML files when all you want to do is write handle database migrations. Flyway handles everything for you. Liquibase is poorly written and its documentation is not that great either.

Answer (score 4):

Your `<sqlFile>` tag needs an additional attribute called "dbms". The dbms specifies your database provider. As you use a "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" you need this:

```
<changeSet id="18" author="naslami">
    <sqlFile dbms="hsqldb" path="src/main/resources/db/changelog/inserts.sql" />
</changeSet>
```

or:

```
<changeSet id="18" author="naslami">
    <sqlFile dbms="h2" path="src/main/resources/db/changelog/inserts.sql" />
</changeSet>
```

The liquibase docs here http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html

Comment: Tip: you can use `relativeToChangelogFile="true"` attribute inside `sqlFile` tag if you don't want to put the absolute file path.

Comment: That's incorrect. The XSD for `sqlFile` clearly shows dbms as one of the optional fields. This works fine without.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `src/main/resources/` from `path` tag

```
<changeSet id="18" author="naslami">
    <sqlFile path="db/changelog/inserts.sql" />
</changeSet>
```